# Is this a safe way to avoid "Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I wrote a function component like this:

```
export const SiteMap: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

  return useGetSetData<I.SiteMap>({
    title: "Site Map",
    getData: () => IO.getSiteMap(),
    showData: Page.SiteMap
  });
}
```

That works fine.

By the way, my `useGetSetData` is a "high order component" function, which uses `useState` and `useEffect` to fetch data, and which then passes that data (after it's fetched) to the passed-in presentation component to be shown.
Its parameters are:

```
interface UseGetDataPropsT<T> {
  title: string,
  getData: () => Promise<T>,
  showData: (data: T) => ReactElement
}
```

Anyway, the next time I try this is with a page, whose content depends on some other things in the URL, which I code like this:

```
type RouterProps = ReactRouter.RouteComponentProps<any>;

export const Image: React.FunctionComponent<RouterProps> = (props: RouterProps) => {

  const imageId: number | undefined = getId(props, "Image");
  if (!imageId) {
    return NoMatch(props);

  return useGetSetData<I.Image>({
    title: "Image",
    getData: () => IO.getImage(imageId),
    showData: Page.Image
  });
}
```

This produces an error message:

> React Hook "useGetSetData" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

If I recode that as follows then it works:

```
export const Image: React.FunctionComponent<RouterProps> = (props: RouterProps) => {

  const imageId: number | undefined = getId(props, "Image");
  if (!imageId) {
    return NoMatch(props);

  return ImageId(imageId);
}

export const ImageId: React.FunctionComponent<number> = (imageId: number) => {
  return useGetSetData<I.Image>({
    title: "Image",
    getData: () => IO.getImage(imageId),
    showData: Page.Image
  });
}
```

This is a trivial change, i.e. it's functionally equivalent to what I coded before.

It avoids the error message above, and it appears to act correctly.

---

My question is:

- Is my work-around safe, i.e. is this code alright?
- If not then under what circumstance might it fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**not safe**, `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` is just an [eslint rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) that is not smart enough (yet) to realize you cheated

the **problem is exactly the same** as before, explained in https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/

solution would be to conditionally render a separate component (that would call the hook unconditionally) => use `React.createElement(ImageId...)` of JSX instead of calling a plain function:

```
  if (!imageId) {
    return <NoMatch {...props} />};
  }

  return <ImageId {...{imageId}} />;
```

Comment: But the call order is always exactly the same, isn't it? Either the page URL includes a valid "imageId" part -- in which case the hooks and the get-and-show are always called -- or the URL is bad in which case they're never called. How is that not safe?

Comment: And how is an ImageId component different from an ImageId function -- aren't they equivalent?

Comment: the code `if (!imageId)` does not know the info is from unchanging URL - in a future version, the URL might change without reloading the page

Comment: using `ImageId` as a component mounts a new child React element (called "ImageId" in dev mode), while calling `ImageId` as a function just uses the return value as if it was written inline without intermediate element (see in the React dev tools in browser)

Comment: Is a [function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) the same thing as the kind of "component" which you say is safer? If so what's the difference between a "function component" and a "function" (i.e. how does React decide whether a function is a component)?

Comment: @ChrisW not related to functions vs classes, `Fn()` is a function call that has nothing to with a component, while `<Fn />` is using the Component "Fn" - I created a separate Q&A for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/55994366/1176601 with an example