# Difference between <Component /> and Component()

Tags: reactjs

I already understand the [Difference between React Component and React Element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939845/1176601), that using JSX basically calls `React.createElement` which returns an element, e.g.:

```
const element = <Component />
```

However, what happens when I call a Component as a function?

```
const whoAmI = Component()
```

I have seen the 2 approaches in code from multiple developers similar to following (oversimplified):

```
class Big extends React.PureComponent {
  renderSomething() { return <div>something</div> }
  render() {
    const helper = () => <div>{x}</div>
    return <>
      {this.renderSomething()}
      {helper()}

      <this.renderSomething />
      <helper />
    </>
  }
}
```

Are these identical or what's the difference?

Comment: The OP posted this question-and-answer as a supplement to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993845/49942), by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference in number of elements created:

- `<Fn />` creates an intermediate element, the "Fn" itself 
  (i.e. it mounts and renders the "Fn" Component)
- `Fn()` just uses the return value of the function called "Fn" 
  ("Fn" is not actually a React Component, just a function that returns a React Element)

This can be visible in the [React Developer Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools), similar to following:

`<Big>
  <div>something</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <this.renderSomething>
    <div>something</div>
  <this.renderSomething>
  <helper>
    <div>2</div>
  <helper>
</Big>`

For more details on how React works: https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/.