# Why is my Material-ui React combo-box not refreshing correctly?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have prepared the following code for my React component containing a combo-box:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default function MyTab() {

    const [currentPhase, updatePhase] = React.useState(1);

    function PhaseComponent() {        
        return <TextField select variant="outlined" label="Phase" defaultValue="1" onChange={e => updatePhase(e.target.value)}>
            <MenuItem key={1} value="1">Phase 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem key={2} value="2">Phase 2</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
    }
    
    return <div>
        <PhaseComponent /> 
    </div>
}
```

Having executed the code, when I select "Phase 2" in the combo-box, what I observe is:

- the state (currentPhase) is updated correctly;
- the comboBox incorrectly displays "Phase 1";
- if I select "Phase 2" again, the combo-box correctly displays "Phase 2".

Note that I have found several ways of making the combo-box display correct value:

1. Moving PhaseComponent to a separate file;
2. Leaving PhaseComponent in the same file, but moving it out of MyTab();
3. Moving `const [currentPhase, updatePhase] = React.useState(1);` inside PhaseComponent;
4. Replacing `<PhaseComponent />` with `{PhaseComponent()}`;
5. Removing onChange (but of course the state doesn't update then).

Can someone explain me what is going on here and why does my original solution not work? I'm also very curious why does my workaround number 4 work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer to my questions reading [Difference between <Component /> and Component()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994365/difference-between-component-and-component).

In short:

- `<PhaseComponent />` makes the combo-box mount again and re-render after selection, so it assumes the default value (which is 1).
- the described work-around solutions like calling `PhaseComponent()` do not have this effect.